# SVG gradients in favor of CSS gradients

Tags: css, performance, svg, gradient

I stumbled upon [**this piece about SVG gradients in favor of CSS gradients**](http://designfestival.com/a-farewell-to-css3-gradients/).

I was wondering, **is the author right**? **How about performance?** Wouldn't CSS be better? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Lea Verou [has done some tests on this topic](http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/css-gradients-are-much-faster-than-svg/) and according to them CSS gradients are faster.

Answer (score 1):

That article is clearly emphasizing portability and capability, and not worrying about performance.